# C# 8.0 Члены интерфейсов с реализацией по умолчанию

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0

Наткнулся на вот [эту](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1440/csharp-8-new-features) статью, которая посвящена фишкам, которые с высокой вероятностью будут добавлены в новую версию языка.

**Члены интерфейсов с реализацией по умолчанию**

В чем смысл данного нововведения?
Разве в этом случае мы не вернемся к ромбическому наследованию от которого майки отреклись? +Интерфейсы станут еще ближе к абстрактным классам.

Comment: `Records` это одно из самых ожидаемых изменений, по крайней мере мной. Это позволит писать read-only типы без идиотизма со всякими Builder и прочими извращениями.

Comment: Статья на русском: https://habr.com/post/413065/

Comment: @AK, может быть. Однако, вопрос достаточно простой, что бы дать несколько коротких ответов и мне кажется дробить его излишне. Так же все объединено под единым заголовкам=> кто будет искать ответы, найдет этот вопрос.

Comment: @AK, ок вынес на 3 вопроса.

Answer (score 4):

1. Проблемма интерфейсов

> When neither interface directly or indirectly inherits from the other interface, the developer will **need to specify the override** he/she wants to use or write his own override.

Будет необходимость указать/выбрать нужную реализацию.

2. Caller Argument Expression

Получается так. Удобно для внешней валидации. [Тут можно посмотреть зачем придумали.](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/caller-argument-expression.md)

3. Records

Это скорее для моделей, которые просто хранят. Единственный функционал, который от них нужен - это сравнение. И с этим Records справляются. [Примеры и мотивация разработчиков.](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md)

---

Проще говоря, все это для сокращение кода.

Comment: По просьбам, разбил на 3 вопроса. Можете продублировать отдельные куски своего ответа сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/903803/c-8-0-records-%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE и сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/903801/c-8-0-caller-argument-expression ?