# C# 8.0 Caller Argument Expression

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0

Наткнулся на вот [эту](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1440/csharp-8-new-features) статью, которая посвящена фишкам, которые с высокой вероятностью будут добавлены в новую версию языка.

**Caller Argument Expression**

Это получается, что компилятор теперь можно будет заставить получить название переменной, которое было передано извне в метод?

Answer (score 3):

Да, если была передана именно переменная. В общем случае можно будет получить строковое представление выражения, переданного в метод.

Ориентируемся, по [соответствующему предложению на Github.](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/caller-argument-expression.md).

Если метод объявлен так:

```
public static class Debug
{
     public static void Assert(bool condition, [CallerArgumentExpression("condition")] string message = null);
}
```

и вызывается так:

```
Debug.Assert(someBoolean);
Debug.Assert(array != null);
Debug.Assert(array.Length == 1);
```

, то компилятор подставит значение второго аргумента:

```
Debug.Assert(someBoolean, "someBoolean");
Debug.Assert(array != null, "array != null");
Debug.Assert(array.Length == 1, "array.Length == 1");
```