# Получить передаваемое имя параметра

Tags: c#, .net

хочу реализовать метод, проверяющий переданный параметр на null. В случае, если параметр равен null, то кидаю исключение. Так вот, в этом исключении хотелось бы видеть название данного параметра (т.е. название непосредственно из самого вызова метода). Сейчас идея такая:

Вызов проверки:

```
        ArgumentChecker.CheckNullArgument(() => nickname);
        ArgumentChecker.CheckNullArgument(() => role);
        ArgumentChecker.CheckNullArgument(() => hashPassword);
```

Метод для проверки:

```
    public void CheckNullArgument<T>(Func<T> argumentFunc)
        where T : class
    {
        T value = argumentFunc();

        if (value is null)
        {
            var name = argumentFunc.Method
                .ReflectedType
                .GetRuntimeFields()
                .First()
                .Name;

            exceptionManager.NullArgument(name);
        }
    }
```

При такой реализации argumentFunc всегда имеет Target со всеми именами параметров (в вызывающем методе они также переданы в виде параметров), из-за чего я всегда получаю имя первого параметра.

[image: Target]

В общем, хотелось бы увидеть более лаконичное решение этой задачи

Comment: `CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute`

Comment: Почему просто не передавать в метод имя параметра? Улучшать интерфейс метода за счет рефлексии, мне кажется - не самая хорошая идея

Comment: @АндрейNOP что-то не получилось ничего с этим атрибутом, нашел пример, сделал также, получаю null всегда вместо имени

Comment: Какая версия фреймворка? Какая версия языка? Как пробовали использовать атрибут? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/903839/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP , net core 3.1, 8.0, как в примере, приведенном вами. Предположил, что дело может быть в интерфейсе этого класса с проверкой (класс внедряется через IoC контейнер), пробовал в определении интерфейса также добавлять данный атрибут, всегда null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

```
public void CheckNullArgument<T>(Expression<Func<T>> argumentFunc)
    where T : class
{
    T value = argumentFunc.Compile()();

    if (value is null)
    {
        var expressionBody = (MemberExpression)argumentFunc.Body;
        string name = expressionBody.Member.Name;
        exceptionManager.NullArgument(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает

Comment: Сработает далеко не во всех случаях. Например `() => null` или если в параметре вызов данной функции