# C# Records. Зачем нужно?

Tags: c#, .net

Наткнулся на вот [эту](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1440/csharp-8-new-features) статью, которая посвящена фишкам, которые с высокой вероятностью будут добавлены в новую версию языка.

Наткнулся там на **Records**.

Немного не понятно, зачем нужен кастрированный класс.

Comment: Это не кастрированный класс, это полноценный неизменяемый класс, для которого не нужно специально писать один и тот же всем известный код, который вполне может написать компилятор самостоятельно. Это нечто похожее на type из F#

Comment: Просто сахар для классов-переносчиков данных

Answer (score 5):

record class - это не "кастрированный класс", а иммутабельный класс, у которого часть важных методов уже реализована компилятором. Слово "иммутабельный" тут - не недостаток, а важная фича.

Такие классы просто необходимы для следующих задач:

1. использование в качестве ключа в словаре: каждый раз, когда вам нужен словарь по двум параметрам, приходится или использовать кортежи, или использовать анонимные типы, или писать свой класс с методами Equals и GetHashCode, причем использовать кортежи в публичном API - дурной тон, а анонимные типы так и вовсе приводят к нетипизированному ключу;
2. кеширование данных: данные в кеше обязаны быть неизменяемыми, чего можно достигнуть или защитным копированием - или иммутабельностью;
3. многопоточный доступ: к иммутабельным данным можно обращаться из любых потоков без блокировок.

Answer (score 1):

Это синтаксический сахар для более короткого объявления класса, который просто содержит набор полей.

В примере из статьи показано, что следующий класс:

```
public class Sword : IEquatable<Sword>
{
    public int Damage { get; }
    public int Durability { get; }

    public Sword(int Damage, int Durability)
    {
        this.Damage = Damage;
        this.Durability = Durability;
    }

    public bool Equals(Sword other)
    {
        return Equals(Damage, other.Damage) && Equals(Durability, other.Durability);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return (other as Sword)?.Equals(this) == true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Damage.GetHashCode() * 17 + Durability.GetHashCode());
    }

    public void Deconstruct(out int Damage, out int Durability)
    {
        Damage = this.Damage;
        Durability = this.Durability;
    }

    public Sword With(int Damage = this.Damage, int Durability = this.Durability) => 
        new Sword(Damage, Durability);
}
```

Можно будет объявить так:

```
public class Sword(int Damage, int Durability);
```

И компилятор сам додумает все остальное: конструкторы, свойства, сравнение.

Если нужен класс с функционалом не по-умолчанию, то всегда можно воспользоваться полным синтаксисом объявления класса. Это нововведение позволит сэкономить код в тех случаях, когда нужен именно класс с набором полей и ничего больше.

Экономия кода указывается как основное обоснование в [предложении на Github](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md):

> Motivation
>   A significant number of type declarations in C# are little more than aggregate collections of typed data. Unfortunately, declaring such types requires a great deal of boilerplate code. Records provide a mechanism for declaring a datatype by describing the members of the aggregate along with additional code or deviations from the usual boilerplate, if any.
>
> *Обоснование
>
>   Значительная часть объявленных типов в C# немногим отличается от набора типизированных данных. К сожалению, объявление таких типов требует большого количества шаблонного кода. Записи предоставляют механизм для объявления типа данных путем перечисления членов набора либо отличий от стандартного шаблона, если таковые имеются.*

Comment: В ответе нет ответа. Ну и зачем нужен этот "кастрированный" класс: `public class Sword : IEquatable<Sword> { куча строчек }`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Дополнил вопрос. Надеюсь, стало яснее. Вообще, я отвечал на вопрос «Какую задачу выполняет новая функция в C#?». Возможно, я не так понял вопрос и имелось ввиду «Для чего могут применяться классы, которые представляют из себя набор неизменяемых полей?». На такой вопрос я ответить не могу, потому что применений у таких классов много. Один из важных сценариев использования (ФП) описан в соседнем ответе и в Вашем коментарии к вопросу.

Comment: Имхо, главная фишка record – иммутабельность, потому что часто требуются простые dto-классы, без логики, но с изменяемыми свойствами и record не избавляет от их написания

Answer (score 1):

С каждой новой версией C# в него добавляют все больше фишек из функционального программирования, и **Records** - одна из таких фишек. Из [парадигмы функционального программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8):

> Основной особенностью функционального программирования, определяющей
>   как преимущества, так и недостатки данной парадигмы, является то, что
>   в ней реализуется модель вычислений без состояний. Если императивная
>   программа на любом этапе исполнения имеет состояние, то есть
>   совокупность значений всех переменных, и производит побочные эффекты,
>   то чисто функциональная программа ни целиком, ни частями состояния не
>   имеет и побочных эффектов не производит. То, что в императивных языках
>   делается путём присваивания значений переменным, в функциональных
>   достигается путём передачи выражений в параметры функций.
>   Непосредственным следствием становится то, что чисто функциональная
>   программа не может изменять уже имеющиеся у неё данные, а может лишь
>   порождать новые путём копирования и/или расширения старых.

Records является просто иммутабельным классом, состояние которого невозможно изменить. В некоторых случаях такой подход уменьшает количество возможных ошибок. Возьмем простой код:

```
MyClass something = new MyClass(arg1, arg2, arg3);
MyMethod(something);
```

Что произошло в `MyMethod`? Никто не знает. Изменилось ли состояние `something`? Находиться ли он валидном состоянии или нужно после вызова метода сразу проверить что-то и вбросить `Exception`?

Самый известный и частоиспользуемый иммутабельный класс в C# это `String`. Я думаю все согласятся, что допустить ошибку при работе со строками очень сложно. Этот класс только выиграл от иммутабельности. Конечно, это не совсем хорошая аналогия с Records, потому что в строк есть свои методы, но если очень нужно мы можем добавлять методы расширения для Records. Несмотря на то, что это не совсем удобно, все равно кода в итоге получиться меньше, чем при имлементации иммутабельного класса вручную.

Comment: а по мне, самый близкий пример - анонимный тип. Разница по сути в том, что теперь он будет не анонимный.

Comment: @tym32167 анонимный тип тоже хорошая аналогия, так как он иммутабельный. Но с другой стороны в реальном коде мы редко пользуемся этим преимуществом. Экземпляры анонимных классов обычно существуют в пределах одного метода и никуда не передаются.

Comment: ну, неизменяемый тип можно и руками написать, потому неизменяемость - это не единственная фишка этих Records. По сути это быстрое создание неизменяемого именованного типа. Анонимный класс - это быстрое создание неизменяемого анонимного типа. То есть из 3 фишек Records (быстрота/простота, неизменяемость, наличие имени у типа) - 2 покрываются анонимными типами (быстрота/простота, неизменяемость). Строки же похожи на Records только неизменяемостью, что делает анонимные типы ближе к Records, чем строки :)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Ниже представлен некоторый псведокод, в котором опущены многие детали, включая спецификаторы доступа и прочую шелуху, которая не важна для понимания. Так же используется минимальное количество полей, чтобы сократить код.</sub>

Представьте, что у Вас есть такой класс:

```
class Person
{
    string name;
}
```

И вот такой класс для хранения экземпляров предыдущего:

```
class CompanyRegister
{
    List<Person> persons;
}
```

`CompanyRegister` — главное хранилище всех персон в программе, поэтому, если кому-то нужно добавить персону, или получить по ней данные, он обращается к этому классу. Для получения персоны по какому-то признаку нам понадобится функция `GetPerson()`, но что она будет возвращать? Пусть она возвращает `Person`, является ли это проблемой? Безусловно. Если мы возвращаем `Person` то любая сущность может изменить этот объект вне `CompanyRegister`!

Но это противоречит основам нашего класса: только он отвечает за изменения (он может оповещать другие сущности, либо же заниматься каким-то слежением за изменениями — не важно). Как нам решить проблему? Если бы мы писали на C++, то мы бы сделали возвращаемый тип `const Person&`, и проблема была бы решена. Но у нас C#, который при всех своих достоинствах, не может похвастаться наличием таких средства как C++ в части «оконстанивания» и предотвращения лишних копий.

Кстати о копиях, мы могли быть сделать `Person` структурой, но это повлекло бы излишнее копирование, которого по возможности все стараются избегать. Исходя из того, что язык в C++ превращать никто не собирается, а в C# [почти] всё есть ссылка, то разработчики обратили свой взор в сторону функционального программирования и взяли на вооружение неизменяемые типы. Реализация таких типов в C# это куча кода, который нужно писать для каждого класса, либо же использовать всяческие кодогенераторы. Вот как, к примеру, мы могли бы сделать наш `Person` неизменяемым:

```
class Person
{
    string name;

    Person(string name)
    {
        name = name;
    }

    Builder GetBuilder()
    {
        return new Builder(this);
    }

    class Builder
    {
        string name;

        Builder(Person person)
        {
            name = person.name;
        }

        Person ToImmutable()
        {
            return new Person(name: name);
        }
    }
}
```

Выглядит чудесно, не правда ли? А теперь представьте, что у нас не одно поле, а с десяток полей. Как Вам? Так вот `Records` делает то же самое, только писать всё это не нужно, а синтаксис создания новых объектов на основании старых становится куда удобнее.

Как часто всё это нужно? Очень. Ведь у нас очень часто есть данные, за которые кто-то отвечает, и этот кто-то не хочет, чтобы их меняли все кому не лень за пределами этого класса. Это очень часто встречается в GUI-приложениях, когда из модели данные передаются в представление (VM и прочие).

Comment: Builder в вашем коде абсолютно не нужен. Уберите его и все станет гораздо проще.

Comment: я не знаю С++, но разве это `const Person&` делает тип неизменяемым?

Comment: также забыли про методы эквивалентности и хешкод, это же важные составляющие неизменяемых типов

Comment: по поводу того, что возвращать из метода, можно да, и копию сделать, и структуру, или интерфейс написать и вернуть его. В общем, эта задача решается не только неизменяемыми типами

Comment: @tym32167, там всё на своём месте и Builder там нужен. Я же написал, что детали опустил, но на деле Name это read-only свойство и без него там никак. `const Person&` делает возвращаемое значение неизменным, точнее возвращает ссылку на объект, который нельзя изменить. Эквивалентность и хэшкод важны, но не принципиальны в том примере, что я привёл.

Comment: @tym32167, структуру копировать дорого, интерфейс ничего не решет — объект всё равно можно изменять.

Comment: поглядите на метод `With` в соседнем ответе, он полностью заменяет ваш билдер. Ну, и по поводу что решает, а что не решает - это холиварный вопрос, я видел разные подходы в коде и они работали и решали все, что нужно. Если вам принципиально это, я могу вам подготовить пример решения проблемы без неизменяемых типов. Я не говорю, что ваше решение плохое - оно просто не единственное.

Comment: ну и по поводу `const Person&` - то есть нельзя будет изменить поле класса (или вызвать метод, что меняет поле класса) или нельзя будет изменить только ссылку на сам класс?

Comment: @tym32167, `With` это просто другой способ реализации, он ничем не лучше билдера, а с моей точки зрения — хуже. Я тоже многие подходы видел и прекрасно понимаю, о чём говорю. Что касается ссылки: объект менять нельзя, ссылки в C++ всегда константные.

Comment: ну, наверное нам нет смысла холиварить, потому я просто оставлю будущему читателю комментариев мой фидбек. Кмк, ваш пример в вашем ответе - это просто один из способов решить проблему в возвратом значения, причем не единственный. И это навряд ли было главной причиной добавления Records. Пример ваш также описывает только 1 положительное свойство неизменяемых типов, не затрагивая другие темы (например, эквивалентость или работа с многопоточностью). То есть текста много, но имхо ответ не полный, так как много вещей (ни неизменяемость, ни Records) не раскрыто.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85494/discussion-between-ixsci-and-tym32167).

Comment: Не могу с работы в чат, не пустит фаерволл :(